# figuring out ASCII style code

Tags: unicode

Iv been looking online everywhere but cannot figure out what this could be. It looks similar to ASCII but only with 2 digits in most parts instead of of one. This was the only place i thought may know what it is or could be.

(i added the spacing my self not sure if it should be here or not )

54 56 32 55 52 32 55 52 32 55 48 32 51 97 32 50 102 32 50 102 32 54 57 32 54 100 
32 54 55 32 55 53 32 55 50 32 50 101 32 54 51 32 54 102 32 54 100 32 50 102 32 52
 54 32 53 57 32 51 57 32 52 52 32 52 100 32 52 102 32 51 53

Comment: What in the world is this? Where did it come from? Without context these are just meaningless numbers.

Answer (score 1):

They *are* ASCII, using decimal code points, where 54 is `'6'`, 56 is `'8'` and so on. Decoding that gives you:

```
68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 75 72 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 46 57 37 44 4d 4f 35
```

But that *again* looks like valid ASCII code points (in hex this time) so decoding them gives you:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdSjh.jpg
```

which leads to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdSjh.jpg):

[image]

Now, if you look *really* closely at the black bit under the white square, you'll see some dots reminiscent of braille. And, in fact, the letters spelled out seem to be:

```
bitdotdoslashwehunger
```

If you enter *that* into a browser as [`bit.do/wehunger`](http://bit.do/wehunger), you end up with yet *another* image:

[image]

As to what *that* is, my detective skills have reached the limit of my ability to care. Since the first image was called `Day J`, and this last one is called `Day K`, I suspect it's a puzzle of some sort and you should probably continue on your own.

In any case, if it's a job interview puzzle process and it's for the same big trendy company I'm currently interviewing for, I don't want to make it too easy for you :-)

I'll probably carry on following the trail just because I like puzzles, but I won't be publishing the results. Good luck in your hunt.

Comment: Cool, but the image reminds me, perhaps it's a contest or something, and we are doing his work too far. Just a guess. It sure is cool, +1, I didn't think the middle result is ASCII in hex again.